# Check a url in content(page) other url by php(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I use codeigniter and want check if exists a url in content other url, return is true else it is false.

for example i want chack for url `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/` that did there is in page `http://stackoverflow.com/` or no.

I tried as, it have error:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://stackoverflow.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $link="http://chat.stackoverflow.com/"; 
    if(preg_match($link,$contents) && stripos($contents,"chat.stackoverflow")){
      echo "yes";
    }else{
    echo "no";
    }
?>
```

Output is as:

> **Warning**:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in **/code/O4savv** on line **8**
>   no

**Demo:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/O4savv

How is fix it?

Comment: Nothing to do with codeigniter...

Comment: Did can change it to codeigniter? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a leading and ending forward slash to the pattern for the regular expression. And also, escape the forward slash that is part of the pattern you're trying to match to avoid conflict.

```
$link="/http:\/\/chat.stackoverflow.com/";
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/PWMVzl

Comment: Why output is `no`? (Unless exists not `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/` in page `http://stackoverflow.com/`?)

Comment: @Kate Wintz My mistake, simply remove the last escaped forward slash and you'll be good to go.